# How to change the points of a polygon in Snap.svg through animation?

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I'm trying to implement a button with a certain polygon on it, which when pressed changes the polygon to something else. For example the play icon on the button changing to stop icon. Ideally the icon should be a polygon with three points depicting the play symbol. After animation it turns into a polygon of four points(A square) depicting the stop symbol.

I tried doing it this way:

```
var paper = Snap('svg');
var tpts = [100,100,100,130,120,115];
var sqpts = [100,100,100,130,130,130,130,100];
var tri = paper.polygon(sqpts);
tri.attr({
    id:"tri",
    fill:"#555555"
});

sqrFunc = function(){
    tri.animate({"points":sqpts},1000,mina.linear);
}
triFunc = function(){
    tri.animate({"points":tpts},1000,mina.linear);
}
```

On clicking the button once I call sqrFunc and on clicking it again I call triFunc. I tried assigning different point arrays to "points" because when I query tri.attr("points") I get the assigned points as return value. However, trying to assign the arrays like this ends up in errors. Any help regarding this problem is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't get any error with your code, however the tranformation does not happen as wished because the triangle has only 3 points.

I fixed it with

`var tpts = [100,100,100,100,100,130,120,115];`

try this

```
var paper = Snap('svg');
var tpts = [100,100,100,100,100,130,120,115];
var sqpts = [100,100,100,130,130,130,130,100];

var tri = paper.polygon(tpts);
tri.attr({
    id:"tri",
    fill:"#555555"
});

sqrFunc = function(){
    tri.animate({"points":sqpts},1000,mina.linear);
}
triFunc = function(){
    tri.animate({"points":tpts},1000,mina.linear);
}

setTimeout(sqrFunc, 200);
setTimeout(triFunc, 1200);
```

another method is to use paths

```
var paper = Snap('svg');
var tri = paper.path("M 10 10, L 10 50, L 50 25, Z");
tri.attr({
    id:"tri",
    fill:"#555555"
});

sqrFunc = function(){
    tri.animate({d:"M 10 10, L 10 50, L 50 50, L50 10,Z"},1000,mina.linear);
}
triFunc = function(){
    tri.animate({d:"M 10 10, L 10 50, L 50 25, Z"},1000,mina.linear);
}
setTimeout(sqrFunc, 200);
setTimeout(triFunc, 1200);
```

Comment: To sum up. The solution was to have a triangle with 4 points where two points are identical.